# Securing my API to only work with my front-end

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, reactjs, tokenize

I'm building a node/express backend. I want to create an API that only work with my reactjs frontend (private API).

Imagine if this is an e-commerce website, my users will browse products and will then choose what to buy and at the time of order they might or might not login.

What is the best practice to make sure my APIs will only work with my reactjs frontend?

What happens when users decide to login or if they remain as guests?

Comment: have you not used express before? you can chain multiple handlers like so `app.get('some/route/here', authHandlerHere, requestHandlerHere);` your auth handler can do something like `req.isAuthenticated() ? next() : res.sendStatus(401);`

Comment: This is at least two questions and far too broad in any case.  Read the docs on Express, PassportJS for understanding routing and authentication, and look up cross site request forgery protection.  Then post code here it you don't get it working.

Answer (score 10):

Apply [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) - server specifies domains allowed to request your API.

How does it work?

1. Client sends special "preflight" request (of OPTIONS method) to server, asking whether domain request comes from is among allowed domains. It also asks whether request method is OKAY (you can allow GET, but deny POST, ...) .
2. Server determines whether to allow, or deny request. It responds with "OK" response and set special headers that tell what domains/request methods are allowed.
3. If client is allowed to query your API, it performs intended request, or bails out...

Clients that do respect CORS (browsers do) will be (or will not be if denied) able to connect. If client ignores CORS (REST clients, CLI tools, ...) it will be able to connect no matter what...

Still, require signed requests (authorisation)

Comment: CORS is a browser policy. It doesn't protect server-side endpoints as the original post is asking for

Answer (score 6):

This use case is an interesting one and I think a problem for many e-commerce sites. The [product](https://www.approov.io/) I am working on has actually had some conversations with companies trying to handle exactly this sort of thing in the mobile space. User logins can be used to tell you who is using the API, but if you don't want to force people to have a username/login you have to search for alternate solutions. What you seem to want is a way of identifying **what software** is attempting to use your API.

There are a couple of straightforward ways that are typically used to address this problem:

**Embedded Secret**

You can add a secret key to your app and require that any access to the API identifies itself using the key. People will tell you not to do this because it is really easy to extract the key. This is true, but with all security there is a cost/benefit analysis to be done to assess how much work you want to put in to protecting your API. The problem with javascript is that it is not that easy to obfuscate or hide secrets because all of the source code is right there.

If you were thinking about an environment where you had other options for your language choice then you can do more to obfuscate the secret in your app (like using the NDK in android for example). Javascript is difficult though.

The important thing to remember with an API key is that you shouldn't ever transmit it in the clear. It is really easy to steal it that way. Instead you would sign your API traffic using the key so that the server can verify that the request came from something that has the key and knows how to sign it.

**Rate Limiting**

Though not actually a solution to the problem, depending on what you are trying to achieve this is an option. If you are worried about large numbers of requests coming from other applications, you can rate limit to a level above what a genuine app would do and you could further block or rate limit by ip address if too many requests came in.

Answer (score 4):

As of today, any user can see what is being passed to your backend by inspecting the network tabs in your browser console. The only way to ensure your api is secured is through user's authentication using JWT or the likes. If your app is opened to guest users, then cors cannot really help because all a user has to do is make requests identical to what they've seen in the browser's console to your apis through curl or postman.

Comment: How does JWT protect it? I can copy the Authorization header from the request and paste it into postman and initiate an authenticated request.

Comment: I think generating a dynamic JWT from Client side would do. However I want to know if I store the signing token in my env secrets would that be accessible to FE clients? If answer is yes then this would fail too :-(

Comment: @ShivamSahil anything that works with frontend javascript is available to the public; so yes it would fail too

Answer (score 4):

I took help from the above-mentioned [solution by @ThePragmatist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709319/6205960).

I have a few environment-based configs on my React website like backend API base URL (ex. staging-api.test.com, dev-api.test.com), the current domain name (ex. staging.test.com, dev.test.com), etc. so I used the variables to create a token to be sent on each public request (from a public request I mean the requests that don't need authorization). So the process I followed:

**On Client side:**

- Create a string with `user-agent/IP/something else from the header` + `request timestamp` + `_` + `random 6 digit string`
- Create a JWT token using any environment config (I used the combination of few like `backend_api` + `domain` + `another config`) as the secret key and the string generated in above step
- Send the generated token in a custom header named `token`

**On server-side to verify**:

- A middleware is used to authenticate any public API request which has the `Redis` implementation to stop the user to use the same token for a new request.
- Verify the JWT token received in the header `token`. If JWT can verify, then process ahead otherwise return with `403`
- Check the `timestamp` received in the request. If the timestamp is of 2 mins or earlier, reject the request with `524` (or something else according to your need) otherwise move ahead
- Check if the token has a random 6 digit string at the end. If not, reject the request as the format of the token was wrong
- Check if a redis-key for the mentioned `token` header value exists. If it does, that means the same header was used in a request earlier, then simply reject the request with `403` otherwise move ahead
- Save the `token` header in `Redis` with `expire time` of 2 mins + 10 seconds (took 10 seconds extra just for a buffer)

This way, all the public requests will send a token which is hard enough to guess by the spammer/hacker as we used multiple configs as private-key to sign the header. Also, they won't be able to use the same `header` in another request. Only the client app will be able to generate the token as we followed multiple things like a header, the timestamp, a random string in the end (just to create some confusion), etc.

I hope it solves someone's query.

**EDIT**:

The random 6 digit string can be verified too on the server-side if we use [TOTP (Time-based OTP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238) with an expiry time of 2-4 mins. This will make the generated token stronger as we will be able to verify every possible part of the token.

Comment: I can easily see what logic is used to generate token from browser, since all secret logic are in Javascript, then use send logic and data (from network tab) to send request to server via CLI or any other rest client. How can this solution prevent that?

Comment: this can be replicated in postman also, and still the postman can send the request .

Comment: Hey @bishwa.poudel , I agree with you. That's why I wrote, it will be hard to guess as it's not impossible. We created many things which can make things hard for the spammer. We can never provide 100% safe solution for APIs except putting high level restrictions on API keys provided to each registered user

Comment: Wait am still confused. If you sign a JWT from frontend lets say you store private key in env variables would that make it (only the JWT secret key) invisible to FE clients at all costs?

Comment: Hey @ShivamSahil, doing anything on the FE would always make it available to clients. We cannot completely hide something from the client that exists on the client's machine basically. I have tried to explain, how we can make it very hard to guess so that for spammers it would be tough to implement the actual algorithm to send a valid JWT every time

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late. But just putting my thoughts here.

Use of reCAPTCHA V3 might help in your case as the reCAPTCHA tokens can be created only in browser(depends on your configuration) and bound to a domains mentioned while creating the keys. When ever a request is made to backend, send the short-lived token created on the frontend. Backend can cross check the token and verify its validity.
Below code provides token using Google reCAPTCHA

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
<script>
grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {action: 'login'}).then(function(token) {
       ...
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this might be a slightly lengthy answer -- but you've posted a rather interesting and important question.

As someone who spends a majority of my time writing security libraries in Node and Python to handle this exact sort of thing, I figured I'd jump in here.

The protocol you want to use to protect your React app and backend API is the OAuth2 Password Grant flow. The way it works in theory is quite simple.

On your React app, you collect a user's username/password (this could also be an email/password if that's how you've structured your application).

You then send a POST request to your backend API that looks something like this:

```
POST api.myapp.com/oauth/token

grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD
```

Make sure you use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type when posting to your server.

Your server will then take this request, run it through an OAuth2 library, and generate two tokens: and Access and Refresh token.

Once you've got the tokens generated on your server side API, you'll then store those tokens in a cookie which will then be stored by the user's browser.

From this point on: everything should be automatic. When your React server makes API requests to your backend, the browser will identify the user via that cookie containing those two tokens automatically.

You'll need to use an OAuth2 library for your server-side, as this will handle things like:

- Generating tokens.
- Exchanging a Refresh token for a new Access token when it expires.
- Identifying the user based on the tokens.
- Revoking tokens if they are compromised, etc.

There's quite a lot more to it, but this is the basic, high level idea.

As you'll notice: there are no API keys involved here. When you're working with untrusted environments (eg: mobile apps, or client side javascript apps) it is *completely unsafe* to store permanent API tokens -- the reason is that they can be easily extracted from source code, or javascript.

Using the flow mentioned above instead is much safer, as you get a lot of protection:

- No permanent credentials stored in an unsafe location.
- Short-lived tokens are used as identifiers. These are rotated over time.
- Tokens are stored in cookies that are NOT accessible to Javascript. This means less risk of web exposure.
- Password are only exchanged once, for the duration of a session -- this means less sensitive information is going over wire less frequently =)

Anyhow: hope this helps!

And, if you're looking for some tools, any oauth library (server-side) should help you with this stuff. If you're looking for a service that can do this for you, you might want to check out the product I work on ([Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/)). It's a paid service, but handles a lot of this complexity on your behalf.

Comment: How does OAuth secure your API from being accessed from domains not under your control?

Comment: It does not. However -- what a lot of people do is create application IDs and assign them to each application on a whitelist basis. This way, you can have a very naive form of 'protection' but only allowing requests from whitelisted application IDs (even though an attacker can easily find this number, it provides a barrier to entry).

Comment: Thanks for providing the above information. It's very useful.

Comment: @rdegges Can you share how you would do integration with oauth protected apis when there is no user involvement? Which OAUTH flow you would use and where would you store the credentials for OAUTH?

Comment: @kbk the only OAuth flow that can be used "without" a user is really the Client Credentials flow -- this flow is scoped for clients (APIs, etc.) that don't directly have a user in a browser. This flow shouldn't be used from a browser, however.