# How can I block requests made to an Astro SSR endpoint that aren't fetched from my site?

Tags: express, astrojs

I was under the assumption that cors is disabled by default, but I am still able to ***successfully*** make post requests from postman to my production app. I want any request that is made to this endpoint to fail unless it is from my site. I could get the origin and validate it in the endpoint but that seems somewhat anti-pattern.

This works successfully in production no matter the origin.

```js
export async function POST({ request, clientAddress, site }) {
  const origin = request.headers.get("origin") || "not specified";
  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({ hello: 'there', origin })
  );
```

I expected the response to fail because I thought same-site requests were the only allowed requests by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is something a client has to respect for it to work. All the main browser do, but most developer tools does not. This is why you can query your endpoint from Postman even with CORS enabled.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45764496/12224431

As per the question of blocking requests that does not come from your frontend, that is an almost impossible task. Clients can ignore security rules and secrets can always be exposed.
The only real solution is having a login system around your app.
See this question & answers: [Securing my API to only work with my front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385813/securing-my-api-to-only-work-with-my-front-end)